# ssh agent forwarding fails with "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"

Tags: ssh, permissions, ssh-agent

I receive a `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent` error message when I attempt to connect from an intermediate server to a third server using the agent forwarding option (`-A`) of an OpenSSH client. The first connection to the intermediate server goes smoothly using a key loaded into `ssh-agent`. The error message is displayed when attempting a connection to the final server.

My OpenSSH client is set to allow forwarding with `ForwardAgent yes` in `~/.ssh/config`, and the intermediate server has `AllowAgentForwarding yes` in the daemon's configuration file. The client config is not overridden by a system level file.

I'm not using a terminal multiplexer in order to avoid an error stemming from environment variables not being set. To run the agent, I use `exec ssh-agent zsh` and verify that both `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` are present in the local environment. I use `ssh-add` to add the private keys for the intermediate and final server, respectively; I verify they are added with `ssh-add -l`.

All servers are of a recent version (OpenSSH 5.3) and the client is OpenSSH 6.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm posting this here because I spent a lot of time trying to find a solution using Google, reading man pages, and consulting a popular book on SSH, all to no avail.

The key to finding the problem was poring over the debugging output.

```
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled: mkdtemp() failed: Permission denied
```

The intermediate machine is a virtual server (RHEL 6.4) hosted by a cloud provider that uses an AWS stack. For reasons I can't explain, this is what permissions on the `/tmp` directory were set to:

```
drwxr-x--- 19  727  727  4096 Nov 28 05:30 tmp
```

Grep'ing through `/etc/passwd` I couldn't find a user with an ID of 727.

Correcting the permissions like so solved my woes:

```
sudo chown 0:0 /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Can anyone speak to the peculiar ownership of the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: no idea why you had these permissions. 1777 permissions and root as owner should be standard for /tmp on all Linux distributions. A wild theory for the strange owner could be that someone was trying to issue `chmod 727 tmp` for whatever reason and did a `chown 727 tmp` instead...

Comment: I contacted the provider and they stated that all new instances have root as owner of `/tmp`. I'm thinking that, when I updated over 270MB of packages after initial boot, one of the relevant RPMs made the change.

Comment: Good on ya for poring over the debugging output. This also resolved the issue I was having, same symptoms as yours.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the entire process to forward keys and get the debug logs along with fix it is as follows:

Create `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host [IP of HOST]
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Run ssh-agent

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

Add the key you want forwarded to the ssh agent:

```
ssh-add [path to key if there is one]/[key_name].pem
```

Log into the remote host:

```
ssh -A -v [user]@[hostname]
```

view the debug logs upon ssh

```
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled: mkdtemp() failed: Permission denied
Last login: Tue Nov 10 22:57:07 2020 from 10.100.28.239
```

while logged into the remote machine view tmp permission.
make sure the user has permission to access the `tmp` folder

```
ls -la /tmp/
sudo chown 0:0 /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

my issue was I created a user to run the server under and that user did not have the permissions needed for the temp folder. I did not want to use root as that is not best practice. The fix was the same. :)