# ssh ForwardAgent, "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have `ForwardAgent  yes` for a few hosts. One of them started failing recently and I can't find the reason.

when I ssh to all hosts and execute `ssh-add -l` i can see one key just fine. If i ssh to that one host, i get "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

I already tried [ssh agent forwarding fails with "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"](https://serverfault.com/questions/557999/ssh-agent-forwarding-fails-with-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authenticat) but it wasn't applicable in my case. I get no debug statement about not being able to write to /tmp as that one did.

here is my `ssh -vvv` output:

```
...
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to host_that_fails ([1.2.3.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
...
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
...
```

One the failing host I can see the `env` variables

```
SSH_CLIENT=1.2.3.1 45320 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
SSH_CONNECTION=1.2.3.1 45320 1.2.3.4
```

on the hosts that still work i can also see `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

Anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you confirm that the ssh-agent service is actually running on that host?

Comment: Server option `AllowAgentForwarding`?

Comment: Maybe you need to add some shell variables, the ones that you see when you start ssh-agent:


    (example)
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-cwIiJn3808/agent.3808;
     export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
    SSH_AGENT_PID=3809;
    export SSH_AGENT_PID;
    echo Agent pid 3809;

Answer (score 2):

I've recently faced with the same issue. The root case was a new agent that has been started and the connection went there instead of the forwarded agent. My .bash_profile contained a logic that started a "persistent" agent instance based on .ssh/environment. Removing this "persistent" agent resolved my issue.